# Use of NVIDIA Tools Extension under Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, profiling, gpgpu, nvidia

I'm trying to use the NVIDIA Tools Extension to perform a more accurate performance assessment of a CUDA code with the Visual Profiler. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for developing the code.

To setup Visual Studio 2010 for this feature, I have added

```
Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> $(NVTOOLSEXT_PATH)\lib\$(Platform);

Properties -> Linker -> General -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> nvToolsExt32_1.lib;
```

However, when I use

```
#include <nvToolsExt>
```

the compiler says

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nvToolsExt': No such file or directory
```

The environmental variable `NVTOOLSEXT_PATH` is set as

```
NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\
```

but the directory `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\` is not present on my system and so I think that the NVIDIA Tools Extension is not installed.

I have two questions:

1) Is the above procedure to set up Visual Studio 2010 for the NVIDIA Tools Extension feature correct?
2) How to install the tools?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file is called nvToolsExt.h .....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the **Nsight User Guider for Visual Studio 2.2 \ [NVIDIA Tools Extension Library](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/NVTX_Library.htm) \ Section 5. Adding NVTX to a Project** has the following instructions:

> The NVTX API is installed by the NVIDIA Nsight “host” installer (by
>   default) into the following location:
>
> On a 32-bit system: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   Toolkit\nvToolsExt
>
> On a 64-bit system: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   Toolkit\nvToolsExt
>
> Both the header files and the library files themselves (.lib, .dll),
>   are located underneath this path.
>
> By default, the NVIDIA Nsight installer will set up the environment
>   variable NVTOOLSEXT_PATH to point to the aforementioned location that
>   matches the system's bits.
>
> 5.1 C++ Project
>
> In order to compile your project with NVTX support in Visual Studio,
>   use the following steps to setup your project accordingly:
>
> 1. Open the project properties dialog.
> 2. Navigate to Configuration > Properties > C/C++ > General.
>      Add the following path to the Additional Include Directories: $(NVTOOLSEXT_PATH)\include
> 3. Navigate to Configuration Properties > Linker > General.
>      Add the following path to the Additional Library Directories:
>       $(NVTOOLSEXT_PATH)\lib\$(Platform)
> 4. Navigate to Configuration > Properties > Linker > Input.
>      Add nvToolsExt32_1.lib or nvToolsExt64_1.lib (according to your system specifications), to the
>      Additional Dependencies.
>
> 5.2   CUDA (.cu file)
>
> In case you use NVTX to annotate code in .cu files, please also make
>   sure the following configuration is setup (this is in addition to the
>   steps discussed in the previous section):
>
> 1. Open the project properties dialog. Navigate to Configuration Properties > CUDA C/C++ > Common.  >    Add the following path to the
> 2. Additional Include Directories: $(NVTOOLSEXT_PATH)\include

In the question you have skipped step 5.1.2 which adds NVTX to the Additional Include Paths. Without the updated include path the compiler will fail to find the NvToolsExt.h.

Section 5.3 and 5.4 recommend moving the NVTX library into your source tree (vs. using the default location) and adding a deploy to step to copy the DLLs to the project bin directory.

Comment: Thanks you very much Greg for your detailed and precise answer. I'm now able to compile, but not to run. When I run, the system says that the `nvToolsExt32_1.dll` file is not present and to try to reinstall the program. Which program? CUDA 5.0? I have checked that the directory `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\lib\Win32` contains only the `nvToolsExt32_1.lib` file.

Comment: In [Optimizing Application 
Performance with 
CUDA Profiling Tools](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/GTC/PDF/GTC2012/PresentationPDF/S0419B-GTC2012-Profiling-Profiling-Tools.pdf) it is mentioned to use `nvtxRangeStart("msg")`, however if I use it as `nvtxRangeStart("msg")` the compiler says `error: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const __wchar_t *"`, but this does not happen if I use `nvtxRangeStartA`. The guide says to use `nvtxRangeStartA()` to create a marker containing an ASCII message. Is there a misprint or is my understanding is not correct?

Comment: @JackOLantern nvtxRangeStart is a preprocessor macro that is defined to nvtxRangeStartA or nvtxRangeStartW based upon the preprocessor define UNICODE. You should explicitly call nvtxRangeStartA or nvtxRangeStartEx if you want to use char instead of wchar_t. This follows WIN32 conventions.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Could you also recommend how to fix the issue with the missing `nvToolsExt32_1.dll` library in my comment above? Thanks again.

Comment: @JackOLantern. Sorry I missed your question. The nvToolsExt{32,64_1}.dll files are installed in C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\bin\{Win32,x64} respectively. The lib directory contains the import library for automatically loading and resolving symbols in the DLL. The DLLs should be copied into the same directory as your application using a post build step. This step should be implemented in the Nvtx samples vcxproj files.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I manually moved the file from `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\bin\Win32` to my Degub directory (where my application executable is located) and it worked nicely. Now the application runs without any problem.